# Microsoft Action Pack - Re-installation of software

Tags: licensing

My office currently has a **Microsoft Action Pack (Design & Development)** subscription.
We get around 10 Windows 8 licenses, and an equal number of Office Professional licenses.

I wanted to know whether un-installing an activated software from a system and re-installing it would count as additional license use?

---

**EDIT**
In this case, it would be reinstalling after a hardware configuration change, like additional RAM/new HDD.

The reason for asking this question is, a couple of users have faced issues with their existing PCs. So most likely the existing hardware configuration will be changed, or they will migrated to different PCs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh come on, this is ridiculous. THis is a technical question.

Comment: @TomTom Where's the technical question here? All I see is a licensing question that's clearly answered in the EULA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Reinstalling implies same computer. THere is no licensing I ever heard of where this counts as additional licensing, microsoft or anything else - there are many technical reasons to do that, starting with hard disc failure.

Moving to other systems may be more tricky and is likely bound to be closed (but again, with MS - read the licenses, you will be safe).

But a pure reinstallation - no, never did, never heard of that doing. In any way. Even the dreaded Mikrotik licenses (tied to the hard disc identity) - support issues new keys when your flash burns.

Comment: Updated question text to ask further on point #2 of your answer.

Comment: No additional licenses. Licenses MAY be tied legally to a computer (which is not the case here anyway), and it is always open to discussion what a computer IS (cpu? mobo?), but in general partial updates are standard. You are legally safe, but there may be technical issues- but that is why you can call MS and make activation by phone. I suggest you read your EULA, but as I said - there are often technical reasons for re-installing.